# difference between union of fields and union of structures

Tags: c++, struct, unions, bit-fields

I'm defining a group of structs to handle some registers and when I defined the structs I found this difference between defining a union of simple fields and union of structs. I'm not sure why this difference happens:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


typedef union
{

    uint16_t all_bits;
    struct
    {   
        uint16_t a:4, b:4, c:4, d:3, e:1;
    };  
}
Example1_t;

typedef union
{

    uint16_t all_bits;
    uint16_t a:4, b:4, c:4, d:3, e:1;

}
Example2_t;

    int 
main ()
{
    Example1_t example1;
    Example2_t example2;
    example1.all_bits = 0x8BCD;
    example2.all_bits = 0x8BCD;

    cout << "a " << std::hex << example1.a << " " << example2.a << std::endl;
    cout << "b " << std::hex << example1.b << " " << example2.b << std::endl;
    cout << "c " << std::hex << example1.c << " " << example2.c << std::endl;
    cout << "d " << std::hex << example1.d << " " << example2.d << std::endl;
    cout << "e " << std::hex << example1.e << " " << example2.e << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
a d d                                                                                                                                        
b c d                                                                                                                                        
c b d                                                                                                                                        
d 0 5                                                                                                                                        
e 1 1
```

Comment: As a FYI: using unions for type punning like this is UB in C++ (even if it is common practice).

Comment: @Frank: Yup, this calls for `memcpy`.  If optimization is turned on, the compiler will optimize it away.... but it will also track data dependencies correctly.  With the union, the compiler is entitled (by the strict aliasing rule) to declare that no data dependency exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pedantic answer is:

Your code has Undefined Behavior. Writing to a union field and reading from another is not guaranteed to work, so any inconsistency you see can be handwaved away as "broken code".

**In actuality**, so many people in the wild rely on this "broken behavior" being consistent that all modern compilers still provide predictable functionality here (at the cost of ignoring some optimization opportunities). So there is indeed something specific in your code that is making it behave the way it does:

In `Example1_t`, the union has two overlapping fields: `all_bits` and the struct. Within that struct, each member has distinct storage.

In `Example2_t`, `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and `e` are all separate fields of the union, so they all have overlapping storage.

Comment: Plus one for adding the comment about UB. That really helps the answer be technically *and* functionally correct.